# Wireshark tcp_dissect_pdus with unknown length

Tags: c, tcp, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to dissect certain protocol that runs on top of TCP. The messages are sometimes split into different packets - unfortunately I do not have a way of determining the expected length of the message (protocol does not announce this). The only way to determine that the message transmission is complete is to wait for a TCP/IP packet with `FIN,ACK` flags set.

The issue is that my dissector is not even aware of TCP/IP protocol (nor it should in concern itself with it in reality). Is there any way to reassemble all packets until `FIN,ACK` is seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the entire TCP connection contains only a single message? You can specify `DESEGMENT_UNTIL_FIN` in `pinfo->desegment_len`. See `epan/packet_info.h` for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, because of how the communication is implemented the entire tcp connection contains a single message (the stream is always opened for request and closed after response). I'll test it when I'm back in the office tomorrow.